# How to create different css styles to different input radio boxes?

Tags: html, css

I have a form with several input radio type:

```
<form class="search" action="{{ url_for('np.bkg') }}" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="query" style="max-width:700px" placeholder="Search over bkg..." id="query" value="{{query}}" autocomplete="on" required>
    <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    <div>
    <input type="radio" name="searchType" id="kmatch" value="kmatch" checked="checked"> match </input>
    <input type="radio" name="searchType" id="kextraction" value="kextraction"> extract </input>
    </div>
    
</form>
```

In my css I have this:

```
form.search input[type=text] {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Now, my question, how to create a different css style for the 2nd input radio type? The current 'input' css element will apply to both radio boxes.

EDIT: I think my css only applies to the first input type='text' tag. So the question is the same, how to make different css styles for 2 different input radio tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for different styles, you can either give the two elements two different classes and define style for those classes :

```
.radio-input1{
   width:20px;
   height:20px;
}

.radio-input2{
   width:10px;
   height:10px;
}
```

or you can give the two inputs, two different ids and repeat the above code:

```
#radio1{
   width:20px;
   height:20px;
}


#radio2{
   width:10px;
   height:10px;
}
```

for classes:

```
<input class="radio-input1">
```

for id :

```
<input id="radio1">
```

Comment: Do I need the prefix search.form?

Comment: no you don't, just give the classes to the inputs. but if you do use search.form, it won't do any harm. then those styles will only be applied to those two inputs or any other inputs with those classes which are inside a form with a class "search"

Answer (score 1):

Try this (for more attractive and user-friendly layout):

```
<style>
    .radio-label{
        border: 1px solid #abc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        padding: 7px 7px 5px 3px;
        cursor: pointer;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px #abc;
    }
    .radio-label.radio-1{
        background-color: #ddf;
    }
    .radio-label.radio-2{
        background-color: #eed;
    }
</style>

<label class="radio-label radio-1" for="radio-1"><input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio-1" >Radio 1</label>
<label class="radio-label radio-2" for="radio-2"><input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio-2" >Radio 2</label>
```

EDIT: You can also play with radio inputs with:

```
.radio-label input{
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        position: relative;
        top: 4px;
    }
```